# What is torque-ampere ratio at electric machines? How it is related with machine efficiency?

Tags: power-electronics, torque, electric-machine

When I am reading a journal about SRM (switched reluctance machines) it said that outer rotor design has better efficiency due to higher **torque ampere ratio**. How it is related with efficiency?

Comment: It's not related to power efficiency.

Comment: Think two reluctance motors with same torque output but different level of operation current. Can be the motor that consume higher current has more conduction loss? (Meaning that less efficient)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Torque / amperage ratio means how much torque produced from consuming a specific amount of current. The more torque produced from the same amount of current results in a better efficiency of the overall machine.
Machine efficiency can be calculated by the following form :

$$ \gamma  = \frac{P_{output}}{P_{input}} $$

Input power is the electrical power consumed from the main grid. Main grid voltage is constant across most nations around the world so power is dependant upon the current consuming.

Output power is the mechanical power available to do some work.

$$P_{mech}=T \omega$$

So more torque / amperage ratio means the reduction of the overall cost and the more available work to be done.

Comment: But we assume in both cases \$\omega\$ is same?

Comment: Would you clarify your question please ?

Comment: "The more torque produced from the same amount of current results in a better efficiency of the overall machine." this argument true only \$\omega\$ s are same.

Comment: Yes for sure for the same speed.

Comment: @NailTosun I was openning your question from the mobile application and it was not clear the \$\omega\$ sign.

Answer (score 2):

You have essentially answered your question in your comments. When considering torque per ampere, it is assumed that two machines that are similar are being compared. The voltage and speed are the same for both machines, but one machine provides more torque for the same current or the same torque for less current. That can be true if the machine that has more torque per ampere has reduced losses, increased power factor or both.